# Can I Write Selenium Tests in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, selenium

Selenium's written in JavaScript. How do I write tests in JavaScript? I tried adding user extensions, but how do I call regular selenium commands from JavaScript? I tried calling doOpen, but that doesn't wait for the browser to load like it should. How do I call a Selenium command from JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can! There is a Node.JS implementation of Selenium 1 at https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda

Answer (score 1):

For selenium 2.0 webdriverIO is very good option http://webdriver.io/