# Simulating user input for TDD JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, jasmine

I'm finding it increasingly difficult to simulate actual user events using jQuery or native element trigger functions. For example, if you have a text input and you don't want the user to be able to add a character, you can call `e.preventDefault()` with the jQuery-normalised event object on the `keydown` event. However, there is no way to programatically verify this test scenario.

The following test passes even without the call to `preventDefault` because the jQuery keydown trigger isn't a "real" event.

```
input.val('test').trigger(jQuery.Event({
    which: 68
});
expect(input).toHaveValue('test');
```

Without the correct code, this test should fail because the input should have a value of 'testd' (68 is the character code for 'd').

Does anyone know any methods or libraries to simulate **real** browser UI events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simulate real event is quite complicated. You must first determine which type of event you need and create it with [`document.createEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.createEvent). Then call different `init*Event` to initialize the event object. Finally, use [`element.dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent) to dispatch the event to the target object.

Comment: I've tried this but they keyCode and charCode kept coming up as 0, even though I specified them in initKeyboardEvent. Any ideas why? It would be awesome if there was a library that could do this for the A-spec browsers... may write one myself if I can get over this hurdle.

Comment: @MattyF This seems to be a [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16735) of Chrome from upstream code of WebKit, that event initialized by `initKeyboardEvent` always has `keyCode` and `charCode` set to 0. I guess you should refer to FF instead of WebKit based browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to try using Selenium: http://seleniumhq.org/

Here's a decent overview:  http://blog.frontendforce.com/2010/05/unit-testing-in-javascript-selenium/

Comment: I had a look at this yesterday - is there a way to use Selenium via JavaScript, so that I can integrate it with my automated tests (JsTestDriver + Jasmine)?

Comment: I don't think you can use them 'together'.  Many people would consider your JsTestDriver tests "unit tests" vs. Selenium being "integration tests".

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for but maybe of use:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091935/can-i-write-selenium-tests-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I believe YUI had some code to do that. Download their code and take a look. I believe it is called `simulate.js` or something similar. Alternatively you can look at how selenium does it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a repo that seems to be kept quite well up to date: https://github.com/mmonteleone/jquery.autotype