# How to send a key to an input text field using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

How I can send a combination of keys (like Ctrl+C or Alt+Shift) when cursor goes in a input text field using Javascript?

**I'm not using jQuery** but am using MS-Ajax. Is it possible using MS-Ajax DOM?

EDIT 1)

According to @Ghostoy help,I wrote this code:

```
function simulateKeyPress() {
            var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
            evt.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, window,
       0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, "e".charCodeAt(0))
            var canceled = !body.dispatchEvent(evt);
            if (canceled) {
                alert("canceled");
            } else {
                alert("not canceled");
            }
        }
```

but when called it I got an error:

```
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'initKeyEvent'
```

and then I changed the `KeyboardEvent` to `KeyEvents` I got this error:

```
Error: DOM Exception: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR (9)
```

where is my fault?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you try to clarify what you want to do, please?

Comment: Its easy to understand the question, here is an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript

Comment: I want to Send keys to a textbox using Javascript not jQUERY.for example How I can send "A" key to text box (I don't write this txt.text="a")

Comment: Why don't you want to say `txt.value = "a"` (or `txt.value = txt.value + "a"`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simulate key events is not easy. See this question:
[Simulating user input for TDD JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770662/simulating-user-input-for-tdd-javascript/6771209#6771209). You'd better try other workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Change
`evt.initKeyEvent(...)`
to
`evt.initKeyboardEvent(...)`

or change to jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot trigger key events as if a user has actually pressed the key.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery) for a relevant question.  You can trigger events for your own `bindings`, like so (JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ghayes/L39Un/3/), copied from answer shown above):

```
 var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
 e.which = 50; // # Some key code value
 $("input").trigger(e);
```

Comment: Hahaha, okay, and you don't want my advice on the topic either, then.  Am I forcing you to use jQuery by using it as an example?  That's not the relevant issue.  Have fun figuring this out!

Answer (score 0):

there is an asnwer! we only need to extend the JQ Event with all its needed attributes, see here:
http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2013/03/jsjq-simulate-enter-event.html